# how to install networkx package on CPython

Tags: installation, networkx, cpython

I have installed CPython [1] on my local machine (macOS Catalina, v. 10.15.4) to speed up computations for function `optimize_graph_edit_distance` in networkx package. Before, I was running the code on Python3, which takes a lot of time. However, when I run the code with CPython (the alias for CPython is python3), I obtain the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/olha/Desktop/GED_optima.py", line 3, in <module>
    import networkx as nx
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'networkx'
```

I tried `python3 -m pip3 install networkx`, but I got the following error:

```
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/networkx/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/networkx/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/networkx/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/networkx/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/networkx/
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/networkx/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/networkx/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement networkx (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for networkx
WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping
```

Does anybody knows how to install networkx on CPython?

Thank you!

Olha
[1]: https://github.com/python/cpython#documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install networkx by:

```
git clone https://github.com/networkx/networkx.git
cd networkx
sudo python setup.py install
```

<s>Try running the following command (Copied from [Mayur Deshmukh's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62670873/8890345) to [ssl not available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62670663/ssl-not-available)):</s>

```
python3 -m pip install --trusted-host pypi.python.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org --trusted-host pypi.org --upgrade pip
```